# We upgraded Apache spark from 2.3.0 to 2.4.1 , after that our production code got broken as spark is replacing null values with "" . How to avoid this

Tags: apache-spark

We upgraded Apache spark from 2.3.0 to 2.4.1 , after that our production code got broken as spark is replacing null  values  with "" . So is there any configuration flag we can enable to make it backward compatible.

We need to avoid this converion . without making any application code change

Comment: are you sure this has been changed in 2.4? I can't see this in the [release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html) - and all other things have been mentioned in the [migration guide from 2.3 to 2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-migration-guide-upgrade.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-23-to-24) - from which source do you load the data?

Comment: can you give some more background on where this replacement is happening?